# jooq sybase code generation issue

Tags: jooq, sybase-ase15

I am using sybase ASE as my database. When I am trying to generate code using jooq it shows following warning.but no code generation is done. Any help thanks in advance!

```
//--------------------------------warning-----------------------------------//
Jul 19, 2016 5:49:17 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger warn
WARNING: No schemata were loaded  : Please check your connection settings, and whether your database (and your database version!) is really supported by jOOQ. Also, check the case-sensitivity in your configured <inputSchema/> elements : [xfuse]
Jul 19, 2016 5:49:17 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating schemata      : Total: 0
```

-->config file------->>>><<<------->>>

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.8.0.xsd">
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.xx.xx:5000/xfuse</url>
    <user>xxx</user>
    <password>xxx</password>
  </jdbc>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.util.ase.ASEDatabase</name>
      <inputSchema>xfuse</inputSchema>
      <includes>.*</includes>
      <excludes></excludes>
    </database>
    <target>
      <packageName>com.gen</packageName>
      <directory>E:/RD/Test/codegeneration/output</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is your schema name really lower case? Could you please post the entire configuration XML?

Answer (score 0):

From your JDBC URL, I take that you're perhaps confusing the database name with the schema name.

```java
jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.xx.xx:5000/xfuse
// database name ------------------^^^^^
```

What you should provide to `<inputSchema>` is your schema name. If you're unsure what your schema name is, then it is probably `dbo` in Sybase.

To be sure, you can also remove the `<inputSchema/>` element and run the code generator. That way, it will generate code for *all* of your schemas in the `xfuse` database.

Comment: Jooq code for tables get created but store procedures and functions are not generated...?any help!

Comment: @BarathRamaligam: Stored procedures are not yet supported for Sybase ASE: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1507. Are you currently evaluating jOOQ, or already using jOOQ in productive systems?

Comment: right now i am evaluating jooq.if every thing goes fine means we have idea on moving some part of our project

Comment: @BarathRamaligam: Interesting, thanks for the feedback. The problem with those stored procedures in Sybase ASE was that there is no easy way to discover them formally via the `sys` tables, which makes it rather hard for a code generator like jOOQ's.

Comment: @ Lukas Eder:Actually i need help on this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559916/when-i-am-trying-to-fetch-data-from-particular-table-xxx-i-got-this-error).Still getting same error

Comment: @BarathRamaligam: Thanks for the feedback. It looks as though that question was deleted by the Stack Overflow moderators. You can prevent questions from being deleted if you explain your problem a bit better, rather than just posting a stack trace. Hope this helps